# How to upload an image in Firebase same as WhatsApp?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am making a chat app in which i am using `RecyclerView` to send images and messages, I am able to upload images in the Firebase and able to show them in RecyclerView when clicking send message button, but when i am sending the image message the image is  showing in the RecyclerView after it gets uploaded because I am accessing it using a link which firebase providing the image after is gets uploaded. What i want is to show that image in the RecyclerView or i want to show a placeholder until the image gets uploaded. i am using picasso library but it is not showing placeholder until it gets uploaded. It would be great if i get progress dialogue just like whatsapp inside the image to show its progress.

Comment: In that case you need to upload two images. First is the thumbnail image which is of less than 20kb size. And after the thumbnail image is uploaded to firebase show it preview in recyclerView and show a progress bar over the image and attempt to upload the original image.

Comment: @ rahul khurana thanx for the ans and can you please tell me how to show progress bar over the image only and not in the whole activity?

Comment: Just put imageView inside relativeLayout and after ImageView add ProgressBar in xml